# symfony Major Problems in config.php issue: getHelpHtml()

Tags: php, symfony, wampserver

after installing Wampserver, composer and Symfony. It seems I can't get it to work. The config.php files shows something I haven't been able to find help anywhere:

```
Major problems

Major problems have been detected and must be fixed before continuing:

getHelpHtml() ?>

Recommendations

Additionally, toTo enhance your Symfony experience, it’s recommended that you fix the following:

getHelpHtml() ?>

hasPhpIniConfigIssue()): ?>

* getPhpIniConfigPath()): ?> Changes to the php.ini file must be done in "getPhpIniConfigPath() ?>". To change settings, create a "php.ini".
```

When bypassing Configuration and going to welcome page I get a blank page with this:

```
loadClassCache(); $request = Request::createFromGlobals(); $response = $kernel->handle($request); $response->send(); $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Any ffedback would be higly appreciated. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it may help some other people:
I was opening the config.php file via absolute path (C:/wamp/www/Symfony....) instead of using localhost/Symfony....
A newbie question finally resolved. Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Your Apache server **not interprets the PHP code**! (check the html code of your page in the browser)

In Arch Linux follow these instructions https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP and edit the **`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`**

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
Include conf/extra/php5_module.conf
```

**PS**: change the `mpm` to avoid *threadsafe* errors

```
#LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```